# How to prevent a service from being called every time an activity is created?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

In my activity, in its onCreate method, I call a service in order to open an internet connection to make a server request. I then save the server's data to a database, and display it in the form of a list to the UI through a CursorLoader (and CursorAdapter) in a fragment. The problem is that every time the user navigates to that activity the connection is launched again, prompting the Loader to reload the data, thus displaying the same list more than once. So while the list should read the same every time, e.g.:

- Sports
- Weather
- News

what is actually happening is that each time the user navigates back to the host activity the list is being displayed again, so if a user navigated to the activity 3 times the list would be displayed like so:

- Sports
- Weather
- News
- Sports
- Weather
- News
- Sports
- Weather
- News

How can I prevent the activity from calling the service every time? 
Also, could the problem be the Loader?

Code for the activity and fragment:

**Activity**:

```
public class HappinessActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_happiness);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.happiness_container, new HappinessFragment())
                .commit();
    }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ArticleService.class);
        intent.putExtra(ArticleService.CATEGORY_EXTRA, 1);
        startService(intent);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_happiness, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and **Fragment**:

```
public class HappinessFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private String LOG_TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

private static final int ARTICLE_LOADER = 0;
private ArticleAdapter mAdapter;
private ListView mListView;

public HappinessFragment() {
}

private static final String[] ARTICLE_COLUMNS = {
        ArticleContract.ArticlesEntry._ID,
        ArticleContract.ArticlesEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID,
        ArticleContract.ArticlesEntry.COLUMN_ARTICLE_ID,
        ArticleContract.ArticlesEntry.COLUMN_AUTHOR,
        ArticleContract.ArticlesEntry.COLUMN_TITLE,
        ArticleContract.ArticlesEntry.COLUMN_URL
};

static final int COL_ART_ID = 0;
static final int COL_CATEGORY_ID = 1;
static final int COL_ARTICLE_ID = 2;
static final int COL_AUTHOR = 3;
static final int COL_TITLE = 4;
static final int COL_URL = 5;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_happiness, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.happiness_list);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader(ARTICLE_LOADER, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    //Uri queryUri = ArticleContract.ArticlesEntry.buildArticleList();
    String URL = "content://app.quantumfinality.com.soulremedy/articles";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
    Log.v("CursorLoader", "Table path built");
    String sortOrder = ArticleContract.ArticlesEntry._ID;

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            uri,
            ARTICLE_COLUMNS,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
}
```

Thank you in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated as there's a looming deadline for the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try two approaches

**1** create a boolean and check if its first time is being called and call your code

```
//static variable
static boolean firstTyme = true;     
// in onDestroy of your service class set it to false. 
// so with that the service takes care of the toggling
/// now you check the boolean in your activity onCreate if its true/false
```

**2** the second way is to check if the service is already running, if not call it, if it is do not call it

```
boolean running =false;
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (YourServiceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            // it checks out to be running so you let fly
            running = true;
            break;
        }
    }
 if(!running){ // if running is false
    // call your intent funtions
  }
```

Comment: I'll try both approaches and let you know

Comment: Your RunningServiceInfo refers to ApplicationErrorReport.RunningServiceInfo or ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo?

Comment: `import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;` @AutomEng

Comment: I thought it was that, but the problem now is that the compiler cannot resolve getName() to my service class.

Comment: It should be `MyServiceClass.class` get it? @AutomEng

Comment: Yeap, fixed it now, but none of the suggested solutions seems to fix my problem. I'll run it with the debugger and if the booleans do change, then the problem lies with the Loader. It just shouldn't display the content every time the activity gets created and I don't know where to restart it.

Comment: sir, the loader gets loaded up in the Fragment on `onActivityCreated` by this function `getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader(ARTICLE_LOADER, null, this);` so any time your fragment notifies that the oncreate is succesfull, the loader gets called, so to fix that too, make the boolean variable `static` and check it in your `onActivityCreated` if its false call that line if not let it fly, get it? or you want me to toss that up in code Sir? @AutomEng

Comment: Nevermind, it was a stupid syntactic mistake on my part. Your first, simpler way of solving this worked like a glove. You might just have saved my project. Thank you!